# How to send specific fields in Laravel Resource

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-api, laravel-resource

I need to send specific fields from the API resource

here is my `User` resource code

```
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use App\Models\MediaFile;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class User extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        $attributes = $this->getAttributes();
        unset($attributes['password']);

        return [
            'type' => 'users',
            'attributes' => $attributes,
        ];
    }
}
```

Below are my attributes

```
"attributes": {
        "id": "1",
        "email": "email",
        "full_name": "Name",
        "permission": "admin",
        "security_key": "alpha",
        "token": "encrypted token",
        "two_factor_enabled": "true",
        "created_at": "2020-05-15 08:56:50",
        "updated_at": "2020-05-15 08:56:57",
      }
```

I would like hide specific fields in specific routes. How can I implement this?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json
You can use $hidden property.

Comment: $hidden will hide, for all the routes. But i need to hide specific fields in specific methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use **makeHidden**

```
$user = \App\Models\User::firstOrFail();

$user->makeHidden(['email', 'phone']);

return $user;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use two approaches:

```
$attributes = [
    "id"=> "1",
    "email" => "pera",
    "full_name" => "Name",
    "permission" => "admin",
    "security_key" => "alpha",
    "token" => "encrypted token",
    "two_factor_enabled" => "true",
    "created_at" => "2020-05-15 08:56:50",
    "updated_at" => "2020-05-15 08:56:57",
];
```

1. **[PHP approach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)**: `unset($attributes['id'], $attributes['security_key']);`
2. **[Laravel approach](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-array-except)**: `Arr::except($attributes, ['id','security_key']);`